# Django shopify auth app has no attribute 'Session'

Tags: python, django, shopify

I have installed django-shopify-auth app. When I am trying to migrate, then the below errors are showing:

```
(shopify) D:\CROSS PLATFORM\shopify>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\tapor\Envs\shopify\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\tapor\Envs\shopify\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\tapor\Envs\shopify\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\tapor\Envs\shopify\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\tapor\Envs\shopify\lib\site-packages\shopify_auth\apps.py", line 20, in ready
    initialise_shopify_session()
  File "C:\Users\tapor\Envs\shopify\lib\site-packages\shopify_auth\apps.py", line 29, in initialise_shopify_session
    shopify.Session.setup(api_key=settings.SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY, secret=settings.SHOPIFY_APP_API_SECRET)
AttributeError: module 'shopify' has no attribute 'Session'
```

I am using windows 10 OS.

Comment: do you have a file or package named shopify ? most likely it is overwriting the importer type

Comment: where is your code ?? please post settings.py code and urls.py code and the code where you are using shopify. 

what is your django version??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Comment: @karthikr yes I there is a folder called shopify.

and @Exprator Please check here for setting.py [link](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/yEeRxPmD) and django version is 1.9  also urls.py:
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

`code` urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^my_app/', 'my_app.views.index'),
    url(r'login/', include('shopify_auth.urls')),
] `/code`

Comment: That is most likely the issue. The shopify package you are using has the same name, so the local package takes precdence.